# query sql não funciona

Tags: php, mysql

Meu sistema está gerando uma *query* a partir de um filtro. Todas as *query* que eu uso em determinado campo não encontram nada, tanto as simples como a *query* a baixo.

```
select * from prt_license WHERE organization_type = 'commercial';
//testei na ide de banco de dados e da retorno vazio
```

Quanto as que o sistema gera, que são *querys* parecidas com a abaixo:

```
select sql_calc_found_rows id_license, organization_name
       , organization_type, edition, licensed_version
       , updates_expiry_date, support_expiry_date, issued_date
       , users_licensed, advanced_clients_licensed, razao_social
from  license_report_view
where ativo = 1 
      and organization_type in ('commercial' , 'professional') 
      and users_licensed between 5 and 1000
order by id_license asc limit 0, 10
```

Já coloquei em minusculo e maiúsculo, mas nada funciona. O campo é um `varchar` de 100.

Não faço a menor ideia o porque que não esteja funcionando, visto que tem outra tabela que também usei a mesma técnica que funcionou perfeitamente.

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado com a segunda query**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: da um trim no valor e na coluna.

Comment: Cara.. eu pego o valor de um form externo, e é gerado um array de um ajax enviado, trato esse array e gero um novo array para ser comparado.

Ai que tá, `$sWhere .= " AND organization_type IN ('". implode("' , '", $query["tipo_de_licenciamento"])."') ";` gero a query desse jeito, porém em outro form, funcionou e nesse não está dando

Comment: Fez um `distinct` para confirmar se esses registros existem? A sugestão do `trim` funciona se é apenas questão de caractere em branco, mas, não vai resolver se existirem caracteres *fantasmas*.

Comment: Como assim disctinct para esse AND?

Comment: Dadas as circunstâncias, parece que esses valores 'commercial' e 'professional' não existem de fato em sua tabela. Então faça: `select distinct(organization_type), len(organization_type) from license_report_view` e verifique se contém a quantidade de caracteres correta: *commercial* = 10

Comment: Mas existe...,, com toda certeza

Comment: Vou colocar um print do resultado, pera

Comment: Tem dois caracteres a mais. O `trim` (como o rray disse) deveria ter funcionado. Tente novamente `select distinct(organization_type), len(organization_type), len(trim(organization_type))  from license_report_view`.

Comment: mesmo com o trim continuou a mesma coisa... o que seria esse caracter fantasma?

Comment: Faça assim: `select * from license_report_view where organization_type like '%\0%';` Eu não tenho MySql aqui para testar.

Comment: Não me retornou nada... vou por o outro print aqui

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57697/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-ismael).

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso. Bloqueado aqui na empresa. Achei esse post no SOen, siga os passo lá para encontrar esses dois caracteres que estão a mais. [How can I find non-ASCII characters in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401771/how-can-i-find-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema não está no select do seu banco mas sim na forma que está lendo seu arquivo txt. 
Utilize a função `trim($arquivo)` do php para limpar os espaços em branco.

Devido o armazenamento de espaços em branco seu select não consegue encontrar nenhum resultado, por isso sempre para testar pode utilizar o comando `length` do sql para verificar o tamanho de seu `varchar`.

Comment: valeu, resolvido

Answer (score 1):

nao sei qual seu banco pq comandos podem mudar mas segue exemplo:

```
select * from prt_license WHERE TRIM(UPPER(organization_type)) = TRIM(UPPER('commercial'));
```

Comment: Eu preciso testar como se fosse um or... então tenho que usar o IN mesmo

Comment: E mesmo fazendo isso... continua sem retornar nada

Comment: Eu preciso que funfe com o IN, pois ele vem de um array, como citado acima, então tem que ser algo do tipo: 
'$sWhere .= " AND organization_type IN ('". implode("' , '", $query["tipo_de_licenciamento"])."') ";'